# macro in VBA to get prefixes

Tags: excel, vba

in my job I have very often to create prefixes. Since last week I think that I can do faster my job with a **Macro in excel**, but I never have developed in **VBA** before and need your help.

We get a list with article numbers from any supplier and then I have to create the prefixes for our System. Our System is looking for the prefix and then it knows the supplier. If the first 6 chars are exactly the same with another supplier, so the prefixes from both supplier is getting longer to 7 chars. If it's the same again, the prefix is getting an eight char and so on.

Example:

```
article numbers from supplier_1:
04012384724993
04012384473373
04012384111453
...
article numbers from supplier_2:
12345671846219
12345629946120
12345629815294
...
article numbers from supplier_3:
12345694724109
12345694715268
12345694724773
...
```

Now you see that first chars from each supplier are the same.
For Supplier_1 all numbers beginning with "040123", so that's the first prefix.
Supplier_2 ans 3 have the same first 6 chars, so here we use one more to identificate him.

```
Supp_2 -> "1234567" and "1234562"
Supp_3 -> "1234569"
```

Supplier_2 have now 2 prefixes, because the 7th position is different in some article numbers, but not the same like supplier_3 is using at this position.

Now I have an excel sheet with column A and B.
In column A I paste all article numbers from supplier_1 and in column B I paste these from supplier_2.
Now I want to run a macro, that create a variable "search" with the first 6 chars from Cell A1 and check it against Column B. If one of the numbers in Column B is the same then variable "search"  get additional the next char from Cell A1 and check again. If now the first 7 chars couldn't be found in Column B, it's the first prefix from supplier_1. I want to paste it into column D.
Now the variale "search" get the first 6 chars from the next Cell in column A, (A2), later A3, ... and check it against Column B.

**I don't know, how to get the first 6 chars into the variable "search".
Can someone help me please?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to approach big problems in as small chunks as possible. Indeed, it may be a good start to assign the first few characters of a string to a variable. A quick Google search would most likely point you to the `Left` function. Here's a link to the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information on how it works and how to use it.

I also suggest that you enable the *Immediate Window*, which can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> by default. Using `Debug.Print` will be one of your strongest tools while writing new code.

```
Sub Example1()

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim search As String

    Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    search = Left(searchRange.Value, 6)
    Debug.Print search
End Sub
```

Here's a snippet to give you an idea of how you might go about solving the next step of the problem.

```
Sub Example2()

    Dim compareRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    ' SpecialCells is one of many ways to find all populated cells
    Set compareRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2) _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each cell In compareRange
        Debug.Print cell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Please remember that StackOverflow is here to help with *specific* coding problems that you can't get over with the resources you can find online.

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulty deciphering exactly what you needed but here is what I have come up with.

I am going to assume that you know how to insert a module into your excel spreadsheet, copy code, and run a macro. If you do not know how please let me know and I will try to assist further.

If this is not what you need please provide me with a sample data set and the answers that you would like to get from the macro so that I can compare as I develop. Best of luck with your projects!

VBA module code

```
'This subroutine will take the contents of column A cells and search column B for matching digits
'   if they are not found it will copy the current search term into column D
Option Explicit

Sub searchPrefix()

    Dim cellContents As String
    Dim tempSearchVariable As String
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    Dim quantitySearchCharacters As Integer
    Dim entryCounter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    isFound = False
    quantitySearchCharacters = 6
    entryCounter = 0

    'counts number of entries in column A
    Cells.Range("A1").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

     entryCounter = entryCounter + 1
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

' gets value of comparison cell in column A
For i = 0 To entryCounter - 1

    cellContents = Cells(1 + i, 1).Value

    tempSearchVariable = Left(cellContents, quantitySearchCharacters)

        Cells.Range("B1").Select

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

            ' detects if B1 column cell content matches the current search terms and then adds more characters if required
            If Left(ActiveCell.Value, quantitySearchCharacters) = tempSearchVariable Then

                quantitySearchCharacters = quantitySearchCharacters + 1
                tempSearchVariable = Left(cellContents, quantitySearchCharacters)
                isFound = True

            End If

            If isFound Then

                isFound = False 'reset flag
                Cells.Range("B1").Select

            Else
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If


        Loop

   Cells(1 + i, 4).Value = tempSearchVariable ' prints the discovered unique prefix to column D

Next i

End Sub
```